# CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore for CSP. How about PKCS#11?

Tags: firefox, certificate, xulrunner, pkcs#11, nss

There exist a function called `CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore` in Windows library. It allows user to select a certificate from a list of certificates found in the cert store for Internet Explorer.

I am searching for the **equivalent** function in *NSS*, *PKCS#11*, *Xulrunner*, where user can select a certificate in Mozilla Firefox browser.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a hint: PKCS#11 does not define/provide any dialogs.

Comment: Do the hint means i only left with two options? :) I am looking the XPCOM, nsICertPickDialogs. Not sure whether that is the right answer as well.

Comment: I have no experience with those but I think you should take a look at [signTextJS addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/signtextjs/) which enumerates user certificates available in Firefox and then displays custom dialog which allows user to pick one certificate for a signing operation. Addon [source code](https://github.com/mozkeeler/signTextJS/) is available on GitHub.

Comment: Thank you. It seems promising.